# Why is my context.router undefined in my react component?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to access my `router` from within my component and it is undefined.  Here is my `router`:

```
React.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        {() =>
            <Router>
                <Route path="/" component={LoginContainer} />
            </Router>
        }
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

Here is the container:

```
class LoginContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  static propTypes = {
    handleLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  static contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object
  }

  handleLogin() {
    this.props.dispatch(Actions.login(null, null, this.context.router));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Login
        auth={this.props}
        handleLogin={this.handleLogin}
       />
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    stuff: []
  }
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(LoginContainer);
```

And finally the component:

```
import React, { PropTypes } from 'react';

class Login extends React.Component {
    static propType = {
        handleLogin: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }
    static contextTypes = {
        router: React.PropTypes.object
    }
    render() {
        return (    
            <div className="flex-container-center">
                <form>
                    <div className="form-group">
                        <button type="button" onClick={this.props.handleLogin}>Log in</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

module.exports = Login;
```

When I click on the `login` button, it hits the `handleLogin` in the container.  In my `handleLogin`, my `this` value is `undefined`.  I have tried to bind `this` to the function in the `constructor`, but it still is `undefined`.

Also, when I put a breakpoint in my `render` function, I have a `this.context.router`, but it is `undefined`.  How do I get my `this` correct in my `handleLogin` and how to I make sure that I have my `router` on the `context` and it is not `undefined`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The best way to keep up with changes is to look through the [Releases](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/releases) page.

In React Router versions that are `> 1.0.0-beta3` and `< 2.0.0-rc2`, there is no `context.router`. Instead, you need to look for `context.history`.

If you use versions `<= 1.0.0-beta3` or `>= 2.0.0-rc2`, the `context.router` is there. In short, what happened is it was removed in favor of `history` but then the maintainters decided it’s best to hide the History library API behind the router, so they brough back the `router` context in 2.0 RC2 and onward.

Comment: I have a hunch that this advice is outdated. I'm using react-router version 2.0.0-rc5 and I'm getting warnings that indicate that the opposite is true. It is pushing me to use context.router instead of context.history. Can you please shed some light on this? Thanks!

Comment: @Ryan had this same feeling and can verify that `context.history` is deprecated. `context.router` is preferred. For me I simply had to replace `history` with `router` in my `contextTypes`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, 
I want to redirect to the login page from the component that need authentication to open.

I used
`this.context.router.push('/login')` it didnot worked for me.

We could reach the path via props so i coded it `this.props.history.push('./login')` since I work with redux store it will update the path in props and it will redirect to home page.

```
componentWillMount() {
        if(!this.props.isAuthenticated){
            // redirect
            this.props.history.push('/login');
        }
    }
```

when the component is open (wrapped by high order component) it will check if user is authenticated. If it is not authenticated it will redirect to homepage.